# "rails-api new" not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api

I recently installed the rails-api gem:

```
gem install rails-api
```

The gem installs correctly but I get this error

```
▶ rails-api new scripted-api
zsh: command not found: rails-api
```

As far as I know (based on what I have read online) all I need to do is install rails-api gem and rails-api new should work. Has anyone else had issues with this at all?

Comment: What is the output of `gem which rails-api`? Seems like it might be a path issue assuming everything installed correctly. Are you using rvm or something to manage gemsets?

Comment: i'm using rbenv. i've done gem uninstall rails-api and gem install rails-api multiple times. attempted to reboot. all the tutorials point to the fact that you can simply install the gem and use the cli tool. i'm assuming this isn't the case. i'm not too great with .src files so would you know how I would path it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After thinking about it further. I realized after yez's response that it is definitely an rbenv issue.  So to solve this I did:

```
rbenv rehash
```

once this was done i was able to run:

```
rails-api new app_name
```